# Do gevent and asyncio code work together?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, gevent

Can gevent and asyncio work together? For example, will the following code work for simple cases? Assuming:  1) many tasks were spawned by gevent, and there were many tasks on asyncio loop as well. 2) They do not share any critical resource.

```
import asyncio,gevent
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
gevent.spawn(loop.run_forever)
gevent.wait()
```

Comment: You might want to look at the [issue](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/982) for that.